# How do I take a screenshot of View in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I want to share screenshot of particular View Component instead of whole screen. 
Any one help me out with this. 
Take a look a picture. Want screenshot of Red mark area which is within View Component.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use library named [react-native-view-shot](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot)

You just have to give wrap your `View` inside `ViewShot`, take a reference of that and call `capture()`

Here is example of code taken from that library

```
import ViewShot from "react-native-view-shot";

class ExampleCaptureOnMountManually extends Component {
   componentDidMount () {
      this.refs.viewShot.capture().then(uri => {
         console.log("do something with ", uri);
      });
   }
   render() {
       return (
          <ViewShot ref="viewShot" options={{ format: "jpg", quality: 0.9 }}>
               <Text>...Something to rasterize...</Text>
          </ViewShot>
       );
   }
}
```

Comment: Ohh! I just checked this before but didn't notice about ref attribute within ViewShot. Thank you

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: I used it, it is giving error "this.ref.viewShot.capture undefined is not an object" taking whole screenshot work but only View refs it gives error.

Comment: Update your question with latest code that you have tried.

Comment: with above code getting an error for viewShot  for line `this.refs.viewShot.capture`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example example of code using react-native-view-shot with hooks

```
    import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
    import { View, Image, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
    import ViewShot from "react-native-view-shot";
    var RNFS = require("react-native-fs");
    import Share from "react-native-share";

    const TransactionReceipt = () => {
      const viewShotRef = useRef(null);
      const [isSharingView, setSharingView] = useState(false);
      useEffect(() => {
        if (isSharingView) {
        const shareScreenshot = async () => {
           try {
             const uri = await viewShotRef.current.capture();
             const res = await RNFS.readFile(uri, "base64");
             const urlString = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${res}`;
             const info = '...';
             const filename = '...';
             const options = {
               title: info,
               message: info,
               url: urlString,
               type: "image/jpeg",
               filename: filename,
               subject: info,
             };
             await Share.open(options);
             setSharingView(false);
           } catch (error) {
             setSharingView(false);
             console.log("shareScreenshot error:", error);
           }
         };
         shareScreenshot();
       }
     }, [isSharingView]);

     return (
      <ViewShot ref={viewShotRef} options={{ format: "jpg", quality: 0.9 }}>
        <View>
          {!isSharingView && (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setSharingView(true)}>
            <Image source={Images.shareIcon} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
          <ScrollView />
        </View>
      </ViewShot>);
}
```